# DirectLine endOfConversation activity doesn't actually end conversation

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

### Issue Description

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-end-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-an-endofconversation-activity, after an `endOfConversation` activity is sent, "neither the client nor the bot can send any additional messages to the conversation". It seems to say the Direct Line channel will end the conversation automatically when it sees the `endOfConversation` activity. However, it's not the case. After we post `endOfConversation` activity, the conversation is just like normal. Do I misunderstand the document? Does it just say it's a placeholder event so that bot can use as an indicator?

### Code Example

```
var event = activity.CreateReply();
event.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
await context.PostAsync(event);
```

### Expected Behavior

After the event is sent, neither the client nor the bot can send any additional messages to the conversation.

### Actual Results

Both client and bot can continue conversation without as problem.

Comment: `Both client and bot can continue conversation` I do a test with Direct Line API and can reproduce same issue, if possible, you can try to [create an issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) to report it.

Comment: Thanks. Issue created as https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4982